# counting items that match within select statement

Tags: sql, select, count, large-data

We have a stored procedure that executes against some fairly large tables and while joining to a larger table it is also keeping a tally of how many records match the corresponding batch_id.  What I am trying to figure out is can I improve this with a function for the count or some other means?  Trying to get rid of the nested SELECT COUNT(*) statement.  The CCTransactions table is 1.4 million rows and the BatchItems is 6.6 million rows.

```
SELECT  a.ItemAuthID, a.FeeAuthID, a.Batch_ID, a.ItemAuthCode, 
        a.FeeAuthCode, b.Amount, b.Fee, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BatchItems WHERE Batch_ID = a.Batch_ID) AS BatchCount,
  ItemBillDate, FeeBillDate, b.AccountNumber, 
  b.Itemcode, ItemAuthToken, FeeAuthToken,
  cc.ItemMerchant, cc.FeeMerchant
  FROM CCTransactions a WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN BatchItems b WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.Batch_ID = b.Batch_ID
        INNER JOIN CCConfig cc WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.ClientCode = cc.ClientCode
  WHERE ((ItemAuthCode > '' AND ItemBillDate IS NULL)
              OR (FeeAuthCode > '' AND FeeBillDate IS NULL))
              AND TransactionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE()) 
              AND convert(char(20),getdate(),101)  + ' ' +   @Cutoff
  ORDER BY TransactionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

When your DBMS supports WIndowed Aggregate Functions you can rewrite it to

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Batch_ID)
```

Of course this only returns the number of rows per Batch_ID returned by the SELECT. if the inner join results in less rows, it's not the correct number.

Then it might be more efficient (depending on your DBMS) to rewrite the Scalar Subquery to a join:

```
SELECT  a.ItemAuthID, a.FeeAuthID, a.Batch_ID, a.ItemAuthCode, 
        a.FeeAuthCode, b.Amount, b.Fee, 
  dt.BatchCount,
  ItemBillDate, FeeBillDate, b.AccountNumber, 
  b.Itemcode, ItemAuthToken, FeeAuthToken,
  cc.ItemMerchant, cc.FeeMerchant
  FROM CCTransactions a WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN BatchItems b WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.Batch_ID = b.Batch_ID
        INNER JOIN CCConfig cc WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.ClientCode = cc.ClientCode
        INNER JOIN
          ( 
            SELECT BatchCount, COUNT(*) AS BatchCount
            FROM BatchItems 
            GROUP BY Batch_ID
          ) AS dt ON a.Batch_ID = dt.Batch_ID
  WHERE ((ItemAuthCode > '' AND ItemBillDate IS NULL)
              OR (FeeAuthCode > '' AND FeeBillDate IS NULL))
              AND TransactionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE()) 
              AND convert(CHAR(20),getdate(),101)  + ' ' +   @Cutoff
  ORDER BY TransactionDate
```

Comment: I did test the COUNT(*) OVER and while it did reduce the scan count from within SET STATISTICS IO ON, it increased the subtree cost of the plan.  So now let me test the INNER JOIN of the subquery and see how that performs.